# How to add and validate custom fields into checkout block in WooCommerce Block plugin?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, woocommerce, gutenberg-blocks

I am trying to add custom field within WooCommerce Checkout Block, so I added a forced Inner Block by following [this document](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-gutenberg-products-block/tree/trunk/packages/checkout/blocks-registry).And it all works pretty good, But whenever I click place order the custom field that I added is not get validated.
How can I validate the custom inner blocks?

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WooCommerce blocks are only compatibile with some extensions. Such as Payment Gateways,Product Add-Ons etc. And some of the extensions that are known to be currently incompatible with Cart & Checkout blocks are Checkout Field Editor,Checkout Addons, Cart Add-ons, Amazon Pay etc.

WooCommerce itself mentioned that the extensibility interfaces for the cart and checkout blocks are still being developed, So they suggest us to keep using the shortcode based checkout for now.

[WooCommerce block extensibility](https://woocommerce.com/document/cart-checkout-blocks-support-status/)

Comment: It is Dec 2023, and it is still not easily possible to extend these blocks...